# How can I retrofit these GX24q lights with BR30 led lights?

Tags: led, retrofit

I bought some Philips Hue retrofit recessed BR30 smart lights to replace my kitchen lights.

My current lights are [GX24Q bulbs](https://a.co/d/cCtn6XD). I know I need to bypass the ballast.

Here’s picture of the light kit and connector and my current bulbs: https://imgur.com/a/vjLeqwu

With my basic research I saw a few options and wanted to know which was best:

1. Take the E26 connector and take off the base screw and take those pigtail wires and connect directly to the connectors after I remove the ballast.
2. Buy a GX24Q to E26 adapter like [this](https://a.co/d/5YzQSMX) one, and make sure I remove the ballast.

Was there an option where I can find a GX24Q end that could plug directly into the downlight?

Was there an alternative option?

Comment: No way to simply replace the whole GX24Q fixture?

Comment: You mean remove the whole existing can and swap out for the retrofit lights? I guess I would need to do that anyways right? Why would you suggest?

Comment: Yes.  I have no idea what your existing fixtures look like, so IDK if that's even possible, but it'd be easier than figuring out how to convert between bulb and fixture.